# ServiceStack: No /swagger-ui/index.html

Tags: servicestack, swagger

I am using ServiceStack for my custom service, in stand alone mode without IIS.

I would like to add documentation for my services beyond what `/metadata` does. I thought to try the Swagger plug in.

I have added the plug-in command to my Config

```
        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig()
            {
                DefaultRedirectPath = "index.html",
                DebugMode = true,
                WriteErrorsToResponse = true,

                CustomHttpHandlers =
                {
                    { HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new AuthorizationErrorHandler() },
                    { HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, new AuthorizationErrorHandler() },
                    { HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new AuthorizationErrorHandler() }
                }

            });

            // For automatic generation of documentation to APIs
            Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature());
        }
```

The existing services continue to work, but attempting to access

/swagger-ui/index.html

gives the not found error.  Is there an additional step not clearly documented at

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API

Do I have to actually set up this page myself?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

After more research, using the `servicestack.api.swagger` package only installs the /resource service to query the API.  It does not include any client-side resources.

To get the client-side UI, you have to download the files from the [Swagger UI project on Github](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui), and install the `dist` directory resources yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the [ServiceStack.Api.Swagger](https://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger/) NuGet package should include all the client side resources you need. Try updating the NuGet package as all the client side resources you need should already be in [/swagger-ui](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/NuGet/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger/content/swagger-ui)

Comment: I'm also having an issue for self hosted service stack with swagger plugin, please go take a look at my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356051/