# Swagger not working on a self hosted ServiceStack Service

Tags: c#, servicestack, swagger, swagger-ui

Following the code example at this URL :

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Self-hosting

I created an empty solution, pasted the above C# code into 'program.cs' and ran the following nuget commands to get the required libraries and code files imported :

```
Install-Package ServiceStack
Install-Package ServiceStack.api.Swagger
```

The service runs fine, the swagger meta data is delivered correctly, but when trying to visit `/swagger-ui/index.html` I get the error **'Handler not found'**.

I've shared my basic example code via dropbox :

[ServiceStackSelfhosted.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18527829/StackOverflow/ServiceStackSelfhosted.zip)   (2.5 MB)

[ServiceStackSelfhosted_stripped.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18527829/StackOverflow/ServiceStackSelfhosted_stripped.zip)  (8 Kb but needs nuget commands to be run)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files in Self-Hosting are served from the executing /bin/Release Directory.

Make sure you set the **Copy to Output Directory** to `Copy if Newer` (*or Copy Always*) for all files you would like ServiceStack to have access to.

Comment: So, in this case 'Handler not found' really means 'File not found'?

Comment: @marfarma it means nothing matching the request was found: i.e. route, file, custom, catch-all, raw or fallback handler, etc.

Comment: I haven't looked at the Swagger plugin's code.  I was expecting a call to `GetHandler` that would return the `NotFoundHttpHandler` and was a bit bewildered.

Comment: Yeah I see the files needed 'Copy to Output Directory', but that done, no change in result, still no handler found :(

Comment: @Nnoel try to copy the whole folder `swagger-ui` from your project to `bin/Debug` or `bin/Release` or wherever you compile the binaries to. This worked for me to load the page. Then I also had to change the `discoveryUrl` in index.html to `../resources` instead of `../api/resources`

Answer (score 2):

Apart from adding the SwaggerFeature Plugin, I also had to add the RazorFeature.

After adding RazorFeature, I was able to browse the Swagger UI.

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    //...
   Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());
   Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature());
   //...
}
```